Why Chrome doesn't repopulate all my chrome profiles from the old computer
I am copying my old chrome profiles from old computer to the new computer
The last time I did it it works great. All of my profiles are coppied.
I am doing the same thing now.
But chrome profiles are not copied.
Well, it seems that the profiles itself is copied, but a table that tell chrome how many profiles are there and the names are not copied. If I open chrome I see

See there are no other profiles.
I copied the whole content of
C:\Users\TeguhProg\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

So there are like 51 profiles. And yet when I run google chrome there is only one profile.
